# Python, reorganize array of dicts

Tags: python

To be honest, it's too easy for me to make in JS or Perl, but i've completely stuck with that in Python because of coplexed tools for dealing with dicts/lists. So, what i need:

i have an array of dicts:

```
[
    {"id": 1, "name": "Res1", "type": "resource", "k_name": "Ind1_1", "k_id": 4},
    {"id": 1, "name": "Res1", "type": "resource", "k_name": "Ind1_2", "k_id": 5},
    {"id": 1, "name": "Res1", "type": "resource", "k_name": "Ind1_3", "k_id": 6},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Res2", "type": "service", "k_name": "Ind2_1", "k_id": 7},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Res2", "type": "service", "k_name": "Ind2_2", "k_id": 8},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Res2", "type": "service", "k_name": "Ind2_3", "k_id": 9},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Res2", "type": "service", "k_name": "Ind2_4", "k_id": 10},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Res3", "type": "service", "k_name": "Ind3_1", "k_id": 11},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Res3", "type": "service", "k_name": "Ind3_2", "k_id": 12},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Res3", "type": "service", "k_name": "Ind3_3", "k_id": 13},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Res3", "type": "service", "k_name": "Ind3_4", "k_id": 14}
]
```

and i need to make that:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Res1",
        "type": "resource",
        "indicators": [
            {"name": "Ind1_1","id": 4},
            {"name": "Ind1_2","id": 5},
            {"name": "Ind1_3","id": 6}
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Res2",
        "type": "service",
        "indicators": [
            {"name": "Ind2_1","id": 7},
            {"name": "Ind2_2","id": 8},
            {"name": "Ind2_3","id": 9},
            {"name": "Ind2_4","id": 10}
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Res3",
        "type": "service",
        "indicators": [
            {"name": "Ind3_1","id": 11},
            {"name": "Ind3_2","id": 12},
            {"name": "Ind3_3","id": 13},
            {"name": "Ind3_4","id": 14}
        ]
    }
]
```

Can you help me with that?

Comment: what did you try? what troubles with your solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Please look at this link for advice on how to write a good question - including some indication of what you've tried and what specific issues you're having

Comment: I'd be curious to see a JS / Perl implementation for this that does not work pretty much the same for Python

Comment: Does the same "id" always have the same "name" and "type"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itertools` to the rescue:

```
import itertools

# Assuming your original list is `l`

# if it does not come in order, you need to do this line first, and will probably be less efficient.
l = sorted(l, key=lambda x:(x["id"], x["name"], x["type"]))

d = []
for k, g in itertools.groupby(l, lambda x: (x["id"], x["name"], x["type"])):
    d.append({i:v for i, v in zip(["id", "name", "type"], k)})
    d[-1]["indicator"] = [{y.split('_')[1]:e[y] for y in ["k_id", "k_name"]} for e in list(g)]
```

`d` becomes:

```
[{'id': 1,
  'indicator': [{'id': 4, 'name': 'Ind1_1'},
   {'id': 5, 'name': 'Ind1_2'},
   {'id': 6, 'name': 'Ind1_3'}],
  'name': 'Res1',
  'type': 'resource'},
 {'id': 2,
  'indicator': [{'id': 7, 'name': 'Ind2_1'},
   {'id': 8, 'name': 'Ind2_2'},
   {'id': 9, 'name': 'Ind2_3'},
   {'id': 10, 'name': 'Ind2_4'}],
  'name': 'Res2',
  'type': 'service'},
 {'id': 3,
  'indicator': [{'id': 11, 'name': 'Ind3_1'},
   {'id': 12, 'name': 'Ind3_2'},
   {'id': 13, 'name': 'Ind3_3'},
   {'id': 14, 'name': 'Ind3_4'}],
  'name': 'Res3',
  'type': 'service'}]
```

Comment: Note that this assumes that the input always comes in order; otherwise the list has to be sorted by the `id` of the dicts first in order for `groupby` to work correctly.

Comment: @blhsing noted.

Comment: Thank you! That's exact what i need. God, i have to look into itertools in the furure

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mapping dict to map `id`s to corresponding sub-lists, so that as you iterate through the list (named `l` in this example), you can append a new entry to the output list if the `id` is not found in the mapping, or append the entry to the existing sub-list if `id` is found in the mapping:

```
mapping = {}
output = []
for d in l:
    i = {'name': d.pop('k_name'), 'id': d.pop('k_id')}
    if d['id'] in mapping:
        mapping[d['id']].append(i)
    else:
        output.append({**d, 'indicators': [i]})
        mapping[d['id']] = output[-1]['indicators']
```

`output` becomes:

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'Res1', 'type': 'resource', 'indicators': [{'name': 'Ind1_1', 'id': 4}, {'name': 'Ind1_2', 'id': 5}, {'name': 'Ind1_3', 'id': 6}]}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Res2', 'type': 'service', 'indicators': [{'name': 'Ind2_1', 'id': 7}, {'name': 'Ind2_2', 'id': 8}, {'name': 'Ind2_3', 'id': 9}, {'name': 'Ind2_4', 'id': 10}]}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'Res3', 'type': 'service', 'indicators': [{'name': 'Ind3_1', 'id': 11}, {'name': 'Ind3_2', 'id': 12}, {'name': 'Ind3_3', 'id': 13}, {'name': 'Ind3_4', 'id': 14}]}]
```